# JSON_ARRAYAGG return value with "\"

Tags: oracle, json-arrayagg

I am using json_arrayagg in Oracle to create a json array from multiple rows in a table. Here are details:

```
create table classInfo (classId integer, category CLOB);
insert into classInfo(1, '{"category":"AAA"}');
insert into classInfo(2, '{"category":"BBB"}');
commit;


select json_arrayagg(category returning clob) from classInfo;
```

The output has a \ along with " as following:

```
["{\"category\""AAA\"}", "{\"category\":\"BBB\"}"]
```

How can I get ride off those \ ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What interface are you using to run your query? I don't see the slashes on my system; I suspect they are not added by Oracle database, but by your client interface.

Comment: Other than that - when you post data for us for testing (which is a good thing!), please test those statements yourself first, and fix any errors you find. Your INSERT statements are missing the VALUES keyword. That doesn't add to credibility!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove escape characters from JSON\_OBJECT output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65291256/remove-escape-characters-from-json-object-output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`FORMAT JSON`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/JSON_ARRAYAGG.html#GUID-6D56077D-78DE-4CC0-9498-225DDC42E054):

```sql
select json_arrayagg(category FORMAT JSON RETURNING CLOB) from classInfo;
```

Which outputs:

> | JSON_ARRAYAGG(CATEGORYFORMATJSONRETURNINGCLOB) |
> | --- |
> | [{"category":"AAA"},{"category":"BBB"}] |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=76334421630247c79f66750576133d68)*